# How to show received values from Viewcontroller B to Viewcontroller A tableview custom cell textview using Swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

My scenario, I am passing the value from `Viewcontroller B` to `Viewcontroller A`. In `Viewcontroller A` I am maintaining tableview with `CustomCell` `textview` (Only one row I am using). In this textview I need to show which I received value from `Viewcontroller B`. Here, below code I am using. Please provide some idea for my scenario.

```
class ViewcontrollerB: UIViewController, isAbleToReceiveData  {

    func pass(data: String) {
        print("USER: \(data)")
    }

    .... 
    ....   

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        // From TextView Placeholder and Color
        cell.from_textview.text = "Enter your text" // here I need to show received “data” from VC_B.
        cell.from_textview.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between VC A and VC B? Does A present B or B present A?

Comment: A Present B and Then B Dismiss with Passing Value To A @Sweeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable that can be accessed from anywhere in `VC_A`

```
var stringReceived: String? = nil
```

Now in the function

```
func pass(data: String) {
        print("USER: \(data)")
        //add the following 
        stringReceived = data
        self.UITableView_name.reloadData()
    }
```

In `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

change the following from `cell.from_textview.text = "Enter your text"` to `cell.from_textview.text = stringReceived!`

So basically use `reloadData()` to refresh UITableView once the data is received.

Comment: Can I get example for dependency injection @iOSer

Comment: Assign default value to `stringReceived ` else app will be crashed.

Comment: StringReceived shouldn't be `let` either as you can't change that value

Comment: Without going into specifics, dependency injection would allow you to have a init method something like this: `init(withData: String)` and then you can use that `withData` variable to store value into `stringReceived` variable. Rest of it will remain pretty much the same as it is now. But coming to realize that A has been created before B, I think dependency injection wouldn't suit the purpose here!

Comment: Thank @dahiya_boy Thank you for catching the crash! Answer edited!

Comment: @iOSer Still crash.. it cant be nil .

Answer (score 0):

```
func pass(data: String) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as CustomCell
    cell.from_textview.text = data
    }
```

Since you are only having 1 cell it will be row 0 section 0 and `tableView.reloadData()` would work as well. but if you have multiple cells and you want to change 1 specific cell its better to just call for that cell, or even `self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation)`

Comment: Run time you cant be sure with the static indexpath. So please add how OP can get indexpath in `pass(data:)` else answer will be not proper or incomplete.